# Hide an element using PHP when loaded on mobile

Tags: php, css

I want to hide the Bootstrap carousel slider when a page is loaded on a mobile device.

Is it possible to do this using PHP?

Comment: Why not just hide it with CSS, using a media type or minimum width requirement?

Comment: Fundamentally you can't do this because PHP is server side not client side so the server will need to gather information from the client before making a reaction, so only on the second page load will the server be able to customise the response to the mobility (or lack thereof) of the client site. So better to follow @Davids advice and use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `$_SEVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` - but then you have to handle a lot of user-agents.

Or you can use a libary for that, for example [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/).

Comment: `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is also fundamentally unreliable (often void) and not to be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
var width = $(window).width(), 
    height = $(window).height();

if (width < 720) {
    $('.carousel').remove();
}
```

Comment: The question did not ask for jQuery, not even JavaScript. Thus, this is a hugely irrelevant answer. If the question does not include explicitly the jQuery tag, your answer should not include it because it's not helpful.

Comment: there its no way to change css after page load without using javascript

Comment: Then use regular pure JavaScript?

Comment: As you wish   bro

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

or if you want something more 'complex':

> http://mobiledetect.net/

However, the best solution to hide a div on mobile is css.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.SliderClass{
    display:none;
 }  
}
```

If you use bootstrap you can use the classes hidden-sm or hidden-xs if you don't want the carousel on mobile.

Comment: codex link? where did he said he is using WordPress?